# How do I save curry with too much cumin?

Tags: spices, flavor

I think I may have added too much cumin in my curry sauce last night and it has this dry seasoning taste in every bite.  It may have soaked into the veggies as well... Is there a way to save the curry that is left? An ingredient or something to balance it out?

Comment: When/how did you add the cumin?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dry seasoning taste it's possible that the spice simply wan't cooked enough. If you added a load of cumin (or other dry spice ) at the very end then it may not have had enough exposure to heat. If this is the case then simply cooking it for 10-15 minutes may improve it somewhat.

One thing that has worked for me before in similar cases is adding some yogurt or a dab of cream and cooking it for a bit. I think it may be that the fats in them help the cumin to release their essential oils, or it could be that the flavors of the milk have some sort of interaction. The reason it has worked is unknown to me.

Beyond that there's nothing you can do that I know of. A bit of cooking work yogurt is probably worth your time and effort to save it, but any more than that is likely a waste of your time and money.

Comment: Another good option is coconut milk. I had a similar experience when I made a curry mix. My jamaican friend passionately suggested adding coconut milk (she couldn't imagine curry without it).

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to fix when you have added spices more than the required amount. 
If you have added more chili powder : Add some coconut milk or desiccated coconut, or cream or a spoon of yogurt.

for cumin powder : Add pepper,crushed garlic and cook in a low flame and make ur sauce thick. 
This will complement cumin and bring in a different taste and flavor(hopefully of ur liking)

a small tip : if you had any spice ,esp for curry always add it before pouring water. 
Normally in Indian cooking you add spices after you add your vegetables or meat, so mix well and cook the spices slowly ,so that the oil oozes out of the spices. This way you wont get a woody taste while you have ur curry.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple soloution is to make a second batch of curry with less of the offending ingredient, and combine the two.  I personally would also liquidise the 1st batch so that the flavours can combine more easily.